# Would you help me with understanding these words?

Tags: vocabulary

DOCTORSHIP

Doctorate

Would anyone tell me which one do you use? and is there any difference between them?

I can not find anything useful as to this matter.

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that the words' meanings are the same. However, 'Doctorship' is archaic.

> [Doctorship (n)](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/doctorship) - (university, archaic) the degree of doctor, **a doctorate**

The [FreeDictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Doctorship) also describes the same when you search for 'Doctorship'.